# {fmt}: always compile-time check format string in function

Tags: c++, constexpr, compile-time, fmt

I am trying to create a custom error class, whose constructor creates error message by passing arguments to `fmt::format()`. I would prefer it to always compile-time check the format string against arguments, without me having to explicitly use `FMT_STRING()` each time I throw. Something like:

```
class Err : public std::exception 
{
private:
    std::string m_text;
public: 
    template <typename S, typename... Args>
    Err(const S& format, Args&&... args) {
        m_text = fmt::format(FMT_STRING(format), args...);
    }
    
    virtual const char* what() const noexcept {return m_text.c_str();}
};

// ------------------------ 

throw Err("Error {:d}", 10);     // works
throw Err("Error {:d}", "abc");  // cause Compile-time error
```

With the preceding code I get error on FMT_STRING() macro:

```
error C2326: 'Err::{ctor}::<lambda_1>::()::FMT_COMPILE_STRING::operator fmt::v7::basic_string_view<char>(void) const': function cannot access 'format' 
message : see reference to function template instantiation 'Err::Err<char[11],int>(const S (&),int &&)' being compiled with [ S=char [11] ]
```

I have very little experience with template programming. How to have make this always compile-time check the format string without explicitly using `FMT_STRING()` every time?

Comment: There's a reason the comile-time check requires a `FMT_STRING` **macro**. It's likely impossible if the string is passed as a regular parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced this exact same problem today, but I think that the {fmt} library has improved since, and so here is my solution.

The idea here is to have the exact same call in the exception constructor as the fmt::format call: the construction of the fmt::format_string object, using C++20 consteval, will parse and check the format string at compile time. Then, the format string and the variadic parameters are passed to vformat, which is doing the real job.

```
#include <fmt/format.h>
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>

class Err : public std::exception 
{
private:
    std::string m_text;
public: 
    template <typename... Args>
    Err(fmt::format_string<Args...> fmt, Args&&... args) {
        m_text = fmt::vformat(fmt, fmt::make_format_args(args...));
    }
    
    virtual const char* what() const noexcept {return m_text.c_str();}
};

int main() {
    try {
        throw Err("Error {:d}", 10); // Works
        throw Err("Error {:d}", "abc"); // Compile error
    }
    catch(const std::exception& e){
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

In my version, I ended up providing a override for the constructor that takes a single string and skips the formatting altogether, and to change the formatting constructor to this:

```
Err(fmt::format_string<T, Args...> fmt, T&& p1, Args&&... args) {
    m_text = fmt::vformat(fmt, fmt::make_format_args(p1, args...));
}
```

This is to ensure that the other overload is always chosen when there is only one parameter.

Answer (score 5):

You can do such compile-time checks in C++20 and recent versions of {fmt} as follows:

```
#include <fmt/core.h>

class Err : public std::exception {
 private:
  std::string m_text;

 public: 
  template <typename... T>
  Err(fmt::format_string<T...> format_str, T&&... args) {
    m_text = fmt::format(format_str, std::forward<T>(args)...);
  }

  virtual const char* what() const noexcept { return m_text.c_str(); }
};

// ------------------------ 

throw Err("Error {:d}", 10);     // works
throw Err("Error {:d}", "abc");  // compile-time error
```

Godbolt demo: https://godbolt.org/z/ceGznTaEh